# Xcode header file command click

Tags: swift, xcode

When I used to command click on a Foundation class like UITableViewDelegate, it used to show the header file in its swift form, but now it's getting me to the Objective-C .h file.

How do I revert back to Swift? Or was I hallucinating and it was always in Objective-C?

Comment: That's a bug. If you find the time please file it at bugreport.apple.com . Closing Xcode may help.

Answer (score 0):

It should gives you the output:

- in a language identical to your workspace settings (Swift, ObjC)
- for a platform identical to your scheme settings (iOS, tvOS, macOS, ...)

I'm afraid you may need to create a new workspace to get the doc in a different language.

Or you could create a Playgrounds, and the doc will always be Swift for what's inside.